# Surface Area Configuration in your azure SQL Server

Tags: azure

How do i run  Surface Area Configuration in azure SQL server ??

i need to execute these statements:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1


reconfigure


sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1


reconfigure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The System Stored Procedures docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336237.aspx) for Azure lists `sp_configure` as not supported, so basically there is no way to use that.

As far as I remember, `sys.configurations` is not available either, so it seems system configuration is pretty much intentionally closed up on SQL Azure.

Comment: so that means we can't use those functions, which disable user to create a function to import / export excel file to db or from db !!!

Comment: @JohnKim Pretty much, you may have to look for another way to import Excel than your current one. It's possible that the currently in preview [Premium SQL Azure service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/preview/)  supports more configuration options, but I've not registered for the preview to test.

Comment: oh crazy azure ! what do you say about amazon aws ? have you ever tested it with anything like that or something you have for it ??

Comment: @JohnKim Both Azure and AWS support [setting up your own SQL Server as a virtual machine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn133151.aspx) which gives you full control of your instance. That may be an option if SQL Azure won't do what you want, but you'll lose the advantage of not having to manage your instance (and I suspect pricing won't be as attractive).

Comment: please be more clear, i don't get what you just said.. you mean i should setup sql server as vm ? which will allow me full control ? but it has some restrictions ? or budget issues ?? that what you wanna say ?

Comment: @JohnKim I'm saying you can set up your own SQL server in a virtual machine instead of using SQL Azure. That basically means you're running and administrating your own server exactly like you would if you ran it on your own hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your idea ! I hope that can solve all my issues. And so that means after creating "Windows Server 2008 R2
SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1" I will be as admin on my sql server and will get right to execute those options as well as then i can create relational database and also i can store math funciton in my table header as we can do in normal sql ??

Comment: @JohnKim Yes, the same as running your own server locally, just running on an Azure virtual machine.